# Having trouble positioning figcaptions using the float property

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I'm currently building a webpage, and am using the  tag around an image and two captions, one serving as a title, and the other as a description. I want to float the title to the right of the container, while keeping the description on the next line. However, when I float the title to the right, the description moves up, and is on the same line as the title, but with the title on the right, as shown in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k5cxg6n2. How do I keep the description on a separate line, without using 
 or anything of the sort, and just CSS?

I have also copied the html from the jsfiddle below.

```
<figure>
    <figcaption style="float:right">Title</figcaption>
    <figcaption>This is an example line that I am using to ask my question on StackOverflow, as I am having trouble with positioning using floats and figures.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I know this is a simple issue, but I can't figure it out for the life of me :/

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style="text-align:right"` instead.

Float literally mean something floating on the window, without any anchor. Where this is related position.

> float:right = position:absolute + right:0px

Accroding to the defination from [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp):

> The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not
> static) ancestor element.

In human wording, it 'floats' anyway in its parent element.
Similar to Microsoft Word, if you let a picture can randomly positioned, the picture will no longer pade the words and thus the words can wrap the picture.

Text-align, instead of allowing the element to float, it is just same as text-align in Microsoft Words, align won't change the structure of content but just a single line(paragraph) alignment.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution lol, thank you so much. Would you mind explaining the difference between text-align and float in this case? How come using "float" didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by applying clear right property to second figcaption like below:

```
 <figcaption style="float:right">Title</figcaption>
 <figcaption style="clear:right">
    This is an example line that I am using to ask my question on StackOverflow, as I am having trouble with positioning in 
  </figcaption>
```